# Lodash recursive function is exceeding maximum stack size

Tags: javascript, recursion, lodash

### The goal

I'm trying to create a "deepMapValues" function. It will take a function like...

```
(v, k) => k == 'hello' ? 'world' : v;
// if the key is 'hello' then return the value 'world' else return the value that already exists there.
```

And an object like...

```
{
  hello: true,
  foo: {
    hello: 'bar'
  }
}
```

And return the object..

```
{
  hello: 'world',
  foo: {
    hello: 'world'
  }
}
```

Using it like this... `deepMap(mapFunction)(inputObject)`

### My current function

I wrote this small function using lodash...

```
const mapValuesWithKey = _.mapValues.convert({ 'cap': false });
// this is because I want both the value and key passed into the map function

deepMap = fn => mapValuesWithKey(
  _.cond([
    [_.isArray, _.map(deepMap(fn))],
    [_.isPlainObject, deepMap(fn)],
    [_.T, fn],
  ])
);
```

When I run it I instantly get the crash...

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Which could be expected as the function is recursive and so if not done correctly it will infinitely recurse.

However, I changed it to this (just for testing)...

```
deepMap = fn => mapValuesWithKey(
  _.cond([
    [_.T, fn],
  ])
);
```

And it worked (which again is expected).

But when I changed it to this...

```
deepMap = fn => mapValuesWithKey(
  _.cond([
    [_.T, fn],
    [_.F, deepMap(fn)],
  ])
);
```

It crashed again with the same error. Even though the recursion will NEVER happen in the above code it was still exceeding the call stack size.

Using the lodash code from Github I suspected it might be evaluating all the pairs in `_.cond` before running the code so I wrote my own version of `cond`.

```
const myCond = pairs => {
  return (...args) => {
    for (const pair of pairs) {
      if (pair[0](args)) {
        return pair[1](args)
      }
    }
  }
};
```

But this also still crashed.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here now as it seems to be recursing even when it should be impossible for it to recurse?

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**Rubber Duck EDIT**

I think it might be because the function is evaluating with the `fn` parameter and then that creates the object in the `cond` pair that recurses with `fn` which does the same again and again and again...

Investigating.

**Further question**

If the above is true... how can I stop the error but still pass the `fn` through the recursion?

Comment: Ok... I fixed it. Will post an answer too. 

Comment: Interesting that there is a down vote and a vote to close this? It is a valid question and answer and TBH... for me seems quite useful for other people. If it's to do with the fact that I answered it myself then please see here... https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: maybe the problem is, there is no data to test and no wanted result. btw, dv not me.

Comment: @NinaScholz fair enough. I have been looking at it from a functional perspective so the result and the data in hasn’t been that important to me.  But you make complete sense. Will add a quick update to explain what this is doing. Perhaps there might be an entirely different way of achieving what I’m trying to do. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I realised as I got to the end of writing the question. The recursion is happening not in evaluating the functions with the object passed in but in creating the condition pairs in the first place.

I updated the code to this...

```
deepMap = fn => _.mapValues(
  _.cond([
    [_.isArray, _.map(o => deepMap(fn)(o))],
    [_.isPlainObject, o => deepMap(fn)(o)],
    [_.T, fn],
  ])
);
```

This sorted it. It now doesn't pass the `fn` into the deepMap until after the condition is evaluated and the function is required to run.